# Need to implement a Distributed Hash table for P2P

Tags: java, network-programming, p2p, distributed-computing

I have to implement Content Addressable Network(CAN) p2p Distributed Hash table mostly using RMI.
I have to use it for a look up mechanism for files uploaded by peers over the network. 
Could some one guide me as to how to design a distribute hash table?

Answer (score 1):

your question is quite broad so let me try to focus on one part:

There are many different DHT (Distributed Hash Table) algorithms out there. I guess the most common one is Chord. Once you understand how it works, implementing it in Java with RMI is just a detail.

On the [Chord wiki-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28peer-to-peer%29) you can find the necessary psuedo code as well as references to two specific java implementations - [Open Chord](http://open-chord.sourceforge.net/) and [Chordless](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/chordless/index.php?title=Main_Page). I hope this can give you a good introduction to, how you can implement chord in java. I've also noticed that Open Chord has an RMI package so probably they support to run on top of RMI.

Comment: Thanks but i have to implement CAN (Content addressable network)

Answer (score 1):

You can look into FreePastry -  http://www.freepastry.org/ Similar to Chord and written in Java.